# Continuously detect a change of chksum of files under folder with inotify-tools

Tags: linux, shell-script, find, hashsum, inotify

I just installed inotify-tools.

I would like to continuously detect change of chksum of files under folder /path

Once a change was detect ( under /path ) then it will print

echo “chksum of files under folder /path was change"

example how to check the chksum until now

```
find /path -type f -name "*.jar"  | xargs cksum | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
```

Little similar case is on:

https://superuser.com/questions/956311/continuously-detect-new-files-with-inotify-tools-within-multiple-directories-r

```
#!/bin/sh
MONITORDIR="/path/to/the/dir/to/monitor/"
inotifywait -m -r -e create --format '%w%f' "${MONITORDIR}" | while read NEWFILE
do
        echo "This is the body of your mail" | mailx -s "File ${NEWFILE} has been created" "yourmail@addresshere.tld"
done
```

Comment: I can see, you're using checksum only for alerting if any changes happen, using `git` for this purpose would be better, as this would allow you see the `diff` when any changes have been made and also allow you to keep or `revert` it to the previous commit if you need to. You'd just need to check `git status --porcelain` to detect any changes. Also, you'd be able to ignore some files with `.gitignore`.

Comment: Is this separate from https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/520433/117549??